# Вернуться к началу

Tags: java

1.Выбираешь атаку 1 или 2 или 3 или 4
2.Если ты выбираешь больше или меньше четырех выдает сообщение об ошибке, после этого продолжает и запрашивает "Выберете блок", а мне нужно что бы возвращался к выбору атаки. Как реализовать?

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Main
 {

 public static void main(String []args){

    System.out.println("Выберите удар; 1 - в голову; 2 - в корпуc; 3 - пояс; 4 - ноги");  

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int kick = in.nextInt();

if (kick > 4 | kick < 1) {

    System.out.println("Выбирите 1, или 2, или 3, или 4!"); 


    System.out.println("Выберите блок; 1 - в голову и корпус; 2 - в корпуc и посяс; 3 - пояс и ноги; 4 - ноги и голову");
        int block = in.nextInt();
        if  (block > 4 | block < 1){
      System.out.println("Выбирите 1, или 2, или 3, или 4!");
        }
   }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Обычно используют цикл while(), который работает до тех пор, пока выполняется указанное условие, в данном случае kick больше 4 или kick меньше 1:

```
while (kick > 4 || kick < 1) { 
// код
}
```

Обратите внимание, что используется логический оператор ИЛИ ( `||` ), а не битовый. У вас битовый, а он применяется совсем в других задачах.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

int kick = 0;
int count = 0;

// ask for strike target
while (kick > 4 || kick < 1) {
  if (count > 0)
    System.out.println("Wrong choice.");
  System.out.println("Выберите удар; 1 - в голову; 2 - в корпуc; 3 - пояс; 4 - ноги");
  kick = in.nextInt();
  count++;
}

// ask for block target
// ...
```